# Modify existing CodeLens in VS Code Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code, if your language extension provides it, you will get codelens to show you a reference count above functions, variables, and other symbols. Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6214.png

I'm taking over a project, and one of my first tasks is restructuring. As part of that, I would love to pull references into local/external without having to "show all references".

I went through the extension API example, and have been [looking through the API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api). Afterwards I built a few, mostly pointless, extensions to learn a bit more about how they work. I can insert a codelens with whatever data I want, but now I'm stuck. There doesn't seem to be a way to get the existing codelens, or really, do anything to access that information that built the "i references".

Another clue I found along my way: The way this works is by the language defining the symbols. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to iterate over them either? I could re-parse everything and make my own codelens analysis, but that will take longer than manually checking the scope. It also seems to be more complicated than necessary.

I was hoping for an event that is triggered when a codelens is generated/changed and provide that codelens back to me. It seems like the codelens is bubbled and I have no access to it.

My ideal would be two get two pieces of information:

1. Get the number i from "i references".
2. Get the line it applies to.

Is this possible or out of the scope of the API? I can rewrite the parsing, but something is already generating that information, so I would prefer to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question, eventually. Namely, [the built in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands). Turns out, you can get the document symbols and execute the reference provider using two commands (which I turned into functions here):

```
async function getSymbols(document: TextDocument): Promise<SymbolInformation[]>
{
    return await commands.executeCommand<SymbolInformation[]>('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', 
                                                                document.uri) || [];
}

async function getReferences(location: Location): Promise<Location[]>
{
    return await commands.executeCommand<Location[]>('vscode.executeReferenceProvider',
                                                    location.uri,
                                                    new Position(
                                                        location.range.start.line,
                                                        location.range.start.character)) || [];
}
```

I later chain these two in a separate function call involving certain conditions.

This isn't exactly what I wanted to do (get the codelens return value), but it allows me to re-use what is implemented without having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi, very excited to see your solution here, cause I was almost facing the similar problem and came up with the same idea with you! However, what bothers me is that it seems that these APIs do not guarantee to return complete and expected responses. For example, for some files in Java, the returned symbols often only contains the class-member level, but no local variables; and for references, I always got an empty list. I guess it is a problem of the language servers provided by extensions, have you noticed the same problems and any solutions?

Comment: Hey @K.Symbol, can't say I had that sort of issue. I used this for a specific purpose, to find things marked as global and make them local when it had no external references. I did this specifically for an ERP project I was working on: https://github.com/mjmatthiesen/localize-lens
 You can see what I ended up doing in the code there. I added quite a few comments since I rarely use TS or write vs code extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally figured out that is the LS extension to blame. But, I also want to know if you finally find a way to access or modify existing code lens? Me too found no API to do that.

Comment: I didn't try to modify the existing. This simply hitchhikes off of its existing information so I don't have to rerun that whole process. Since it returns that info, maybe you can try modifying it there, but that's all I can say really.